# Accept additional argument on custom post type permalink

Tags: custom-post-types

I have registered a custom `foo` post type:

```php
register_post_type('foo', [
    'rewrite'         => ['slug' => 'foo'],
    'capability_type' => 'post',
]);
```

If I have created a foo with a slug of `bar` I can access it with

```
https://www.example.com/foo/bar/
```

I'd like to add an additional parameter to the end:

```
https://www.example.com/foo/bar/baz/
```

It looks like I need to add a `ep_mask` key to the `rewrite` array, but I am not sure how.  The `baz` part will vary and be used to generate the page differently.

Comment: From where is the `baz` part? Is it a custom field? What's the meta key?

Comment: Can you provide some context around this by explaining why or what this is trying to achieve? The example here has been made deliberatley generic, perhaps too generic

Comment: `baz` is just something that will be put in to the URL.  For the purpose of the question, assume it can be anything and is not related to _anything_ in the database.

Comment: @Jerry, have you checked/tried [`add_rewrite_rule`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_rewrite_rule/)?